# How to Remove degree (°N and °E) symbols in the levelplot axis

Tags: r, axis-labels, levelplot, rastervis

I am using the rasterVis package for visualizing gridded temperature data and while plotting my raster data layer using levelplot, degree North and degree East symbols appear in axis labels which I don't want to appear in my plot. Please give me ideas on how to get rid of them.
Below is the code I am using

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(rasterVis)
data=stack("C:\\Users\\WKCTIA01\\Downloads\\adaptor.mars.internal-1672364228.5172331-3652-3-525a4eb6-3d38-4e31-a6a5-89ad76842ed9\\data.nc")
levelplot(data[[1]],margin=F,pretty=T,xlim=c(70,88),ylim=c(26,40))
```

[image: This is the result I am getting]

I searched alot but only got similar issue for ggplot but not for levelplot.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: It may be problem of the source data. I've tried to plot the raster file from ```system.file("external/test.grd", package = "raster")``` with the **levelplot** function, and the ºN and ºE symbols don't appear.